# FullCalendar jQuery no eventClick

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

There is no method call eventClick in  fullcalendar-1.5.3.
How do i handed this issue.

Comment: how do i make my own fullcalendar? documentation said that there is a method(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/).

Comment: Yes there is, make sure you are using the right syntax.

Comment: What is the right syntax? 
What is fullCalendar() init method?

Comment: eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                $("#eventdata").show();
                $("#eventdata").load("<?php echo Dispatcher::baseUrl(); ?>/events/edit/"+calEvent.id);
            }

Comment: @MilinaUdara There you go as per the documentation it is possible, go through the document you will sure find the way to handle your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this (http://duckranger.com/2010/03/fullcalendar-and-cakephp-part-1-set-up/) tutorial and the problem was I had imported only

```
echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('ui.core.js');
echo $javascript->link('ui.resizable.js');
echo $javascript->link('fullcalendar.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('ui.draggable.js');
echo $html->css('fullcalendar');
```

I haven't imported the `fullcalendar.js`